# Is it a bad idea to expose the Schema Structure at source code?

Tags: security, schema, jsonschema

From security point of view, is it a bad idea to expose to the end user (browser) how the data is structured?

I was looking into JSON-SCHEMA, (over-worryingly) trying to think about this if it could cause vulnerabilities and/or make it easier for competition to reverse engineer your end product(s)?

**2 topics I can think of I would like to know the answers to (unless there is more):**

1. Vulnerability
2. Reverse Engineer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that anybody who can see the JSON Schema can also see the data following that schema (using standard debugging tools bundled into any browser).

Unless your data structure is deliberately obfuscated (which is an ineffective security measure), it should be fairly straightforward for someone to figure out the shape of your data just by looking at the examples being sent back and forth during normal operation of the client.  Public documentation will make their life easier by at most ten minutes.

Also (thinking of JSON APIs here, but I think it's true more generally), a situation where the security of your system *in any way* depends on the secrecy of the data *format* is a super-big bright-red warning sign.  If you have a super-secret flag in your data (e.g. `{"passwordOverride": true}` :p) or other properties that could be used by an attacker to mess things up (for anyone aside from themselves) then your system is already broken.

There should be zero harm in a clearly-documented API - in fact, a clearly documented API is probably easier for you and any other collaborators to audit for security.  If my API has a security hole in it, I'd honestly rather it be obvious so I/others can notice and fix it.

Comment: That makes so much sense (especially the last paragraph)

Answer (score 1):

People who worked in the data layer are the only people who knows if the exposed data structure are remotely the same as how your db schema looks. For end users, all they can assume are, the structure is not the same, the structure is the same, the structure is similar but varies. And all these assumptions has the same probability to be true, therefore, you can obscure your exposed data or keep it identical to the DB schema, you would have the same probability and vulnerability. It is best to not keep it identical.